# Undefined reference when using ta-lib/ta_lib.h file and Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, shared, ta-lib

I want to use the ta_lib functions in my C code and am trying to import the ta_lib functions. The header file gets imported correctly but i cannot get the linker to find the actual library.
I want to do the compiling process with MAKE and gcc.

Firstly I import the header

```cpp
#include <ta-lib/ta_libc.h>
```

And then when i need to use a function

```cpp
TA_ADOSC(0, CSV_LENGTH - 1, temp_high, temp_low, temp_close, temp_volume, 3, 10, &beginIdx, &endIdx, tmp_adosc);
```

The program compiles fine using my makefile

```
# create CC variable

CC = gcc

# create CFLAGS variable

CFLAGS =  -L/usr/local/lib -Wall -g

LDLIBS = -lta_lib -I/usr/local/include -lm

output: main.o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o output main.o

main.o: main.c
$(CC) $(LDLIBS) -c main.c

# target: dependencies

# action

clean:
rm -f \*.o output
```

Once I try to run `make` i get the following

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -Wall -g -o output main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `calculate_indicators': main.c:(.text+0x226): undefined reference to `TA_ADOSC'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:10: output\] Error 1
```

From my understanding I need to fix the linking to the shared library.

The library is installed:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libta_lib.so
```

Returns the following

```
    libta_lib.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libta_lib.so.0
    libta_lib.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libta_lib.so.0
    libta_lib.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libta_lib.so
    libta_lib.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libta_lib.so
```

Since i am fairly new to C and using external libraries I can't find what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the libraries to the **compile** line.  They need to be added to the **link** line.  And preprocessor options like `-I` are used by the **compiler**, and "where to find libraries" options like `-L` are used by the **linker**.

Also, libraries *always* must come at the *end* of the link line, after all the object files.  And, the `-L` "where to search" option should come before the `-l` "what library to find" option.

Write your rules like this:

```
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS = -lta_lib -lm

output: main.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o output main.o $(LDLIBS)

main.o: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
```

However, it's better to just let make do the work for you; it knows how to correctly compile things (as long as you set the standard variables).  You don't need to include a rule to build `main.o` at all.

Comment: ```output: main.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c main.c -o output $(LDLIBS)``` should suffice?

Comment: This way also makes the permission denied when i run output

Comment: If you want to build everything with a single command you don't need a makefile.  You can just put that into a shell script.  However, your command line is wrong because the `-c` option tells the compiler to generate an object file and not link a program.  You have to remove that option if you want to compile and link all in one command.